# Key error (None of dict values).On using enron dataset

Tags: python, pandas, word2vec, kaggle

```
import pandas as pd
enrond_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(final_embeddings)
enrond_dataframe = enrond_dataframe.set_index([ reverse_dictionary.values()])
enrond_dataframe.head()
```

im getting the error as

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-0328d6643879> in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 enrond_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(final_embeddings)
----> 3 enrond_dataframe = enrond_dataframe.set_index([ reverse_dictionary.values()])
      4 enrond_dataframe.head()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in set_index(self, keys, drop, append, inplace, verify_integrity)
   4301 
   4302         if missing:
-> 4303             raise KeyError(f"None of {missing} are in the columns")
   4304 
   4305         if inplace:

KeyError: "None of [dict_values(['UNK', 'the', 'ect', 'to', 'enron', 'hou', 'and', 'a', 'of', 'on', 'you', 'i',...
```

I was getting a key error above also but i modified it using
vocabulary_size = len(dictionary)
print('Dictionary size', len(dictionary))
in last steps of setp2 of word2vec

Comment: you may need to unpack the values: `enrond_dataframe = enrond_dataframe.set_index([*reverse_dictionary.values()])` or `enrond_dataframe.set_index(list(reverse_dictionary.values()))`

Comment: still getting the same error

Comment: What is `print(enrond_dataframe.columns)`  are the values in the dictionary present as columns in the dataframe? if not what do you expect?

Comment: on printing print(enrond_dataframe.columns) i get  RangeIndex(start=0, stop=300, step=1)

Comment: after printing head im expecting to get the word and its representation in the context of everything

Comment: We can see what's in `reverse_dictionary` but we can't guess its purpose or what you are trying to achieve with this code.

Comment: 0         1         2         3         4         5         6    \
UNK       0.043161 -0.062182  0.088341 -0.025311 -0.017227 -0.036769 -0.019743         ......          ..........        ........... ............... ................. ............ ................         ........

Comment: trying to achieve something like above to get word represntations

Comment: @anky it worked fine with enrond_dataframe = enrond_dataframe.set_index([list(reverse_dictionary.values())]) .Thanks it wasn't working before because of the simple brackets